# Fire does not appear in the final rendering

Tags: fire

I created a fire in the blender, it appears in  the render Mode but does not appear in the final rendering. What to do?

Comment: Does your domain have a material? Volume shader?

Answer (score 1):

Have you baked it? Open Cache settings in fire simulation, set type to *All* and press *Bake all*.

[image]

Comment: When I do this the fire suddenly disappears.

Comment: It dissapeared because you have switched cache type. Bake it, so that it will appear